# How can I get a copy of a Canadian visa refusal letter?

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, applications, lost-documents

I have applied for a Canadian Temporary Resident Visa (TRV); a previous paper application was refused in 2016. I have lost the copy of my refusal letter and want to submit it when I apply for my new visa. How how can I get the a copy of the 2016 refusal letter from Embassy?

Answer (score 5):

The Canadian Embassy would not have copies of such documents, and you should not need to include an earlier refusal letter in a new submission. Such information is retained in immigration files in Canada and a new visa application would be reviewed against what is in the records.

Your 2016 refusal letter from Canada would have indicated the reason(s) for the decision, a tick mark at the general points listed in it. However, it is a standard form letter, and doesn't identify the shortcomings in an application, or how to remedy them.

Canada's visa refusal letter almost always has a concluding statement:

> Should you wish to reapply, I would suggest that you do so only if your situation has changed substantively or you have significant new information to submit.

That is suggesting that a new application may not be successful unless shortcomings have been addressed, and that comparisons would be made against an earlier application.

---

To address the two concerns raised comment, first, how to get a copy of a refusal letter. You can ask for information that concerns you. You must be in Canada to do so and, if you are not, you would have to hire a representative there.

> Send a request [to Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada (IRCC) under the Access to Information Act (ATI)][1} to:
>
> - Get information about IRCC
> - Get information that would have been created by IRCC
> - Get personal information submitted by a representative, where the client (with their consent) is not a Canadian citizen, permanent resident, or here in Canada.
>
> The fee for requests under the Access to information Act is $5.00.
>
> To send a request **you must be a Canadian citizen, a permanent resident of Canada or an individual or corporation currently in Canada**.

---

Second, a generic example of Canada's refusal letter:

[image]

Comment: I'll point out that the question was "How to get a copy of the refusal letter." Your answer — "You don't need it." — is responsive, but it doesn't answer the question. Is it possible to get a copy of the refusal letter?

Comment: @David true, but it also said *from the Embassy* and embassies and consulates do not keep documents submitted at or through those foreign missions. Those who want their immigration records may, in certain countries, request under freedom of information, or subject access requests. In the case of Canada, one has to be in the country to do so, but that is not what OP asked.

Comment: @David It's a perfectly appropriate answer when it _advances the user's goals_ even if it doesn't strictly answer the literal text of the question. In this case the user intends to reapply for the visa and thought that he needed to include a copy of the previous refusal letter. Because he does not need the letter to reapply for the visa, this is a perfectly appropriate answer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hampton Yes, the answer advances the user's goals, and Georgio remembers (I didn't) that one may request this info from Canadian Immigration if one does so from within Canada. The latter bit would have been useful in the original answer, as perhaps the OP wanted to see the document himself, to view what information and conclusions had previously been reached. Had the OP been me, I would have been interested in that information and perspective.

Comment: @David If it were most any other country I might agree. But Canada's visa refusal letters really are virtually useless. They say nothing about the reason for refusal.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What about the example letter contained in Giorgio's Answer above. It contains reasons, or would if boxes were ticked.

Comment: @David If they ever ticked the informative boxes, then probably. But the first entire section is 100% of what we have seen here in the visa refusal questions we've gotten, and as you can see it's utterly useless.